# How to import excel records to a csv file fastly from mysql query resultset?

Tags: sql, mysql, excel, csv, export-to-excel

I have a mysql query producing more than 200k records. I want to export them all to excel sheet.
This should be done within seconds.

```
select location as Location, date as Date, population as Population, total_cases as InfectionCount,
total_cases / population * 100 as PercentPopulationInfected
from coviddeaths
where continent is not null
order by 1, 2
```

I tried this query and ui of mysql, but it is not responding while transporting records.

Comment: Use SELECT INTO OUTFILE with `'\t'` as lines terminator - the output will be saved to TSV. Then open it with Excel.